# Android: Actionbar with ListView and GridView

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-actionbar

I'm trying to develop an actionbar with three tabs. In the first tab I wanna have a gridview with images and in the other two tabs I wanna have a listview. How can I make this? Is there a code example in the internet? (I haven't find one)

Comment: first search the google and post the question search....

Comment: Why don't you google "tutorials for actionbar" ? Almost every search result has one examples and tutorials..

Answer (score 0):

> first you need to create TabBar app with Three Tabs then go for List
>   and Grid view on Tabs.

So I have already created some tutorials to do this.

First Create Three Tabs:

Check this for Tab Bar : [TabWidget in Android](http://www.rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2011/11/tabwidget-in-android-advance.html)

For List View: [ListView in Android](http://www.rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2011/08/list-view-in-android-basic.html)

For Grid View: [Grid View Demo With Images](http://www.rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2011/09/grid-view-demo-with-images.html)

Below is the code how you can create Tabs in Android

**ActivityTabWidget.java**

```
package com.rdc;  

import android.app.TabActivity;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.LayoutInflater;  
import android.widget.TabHost;  

public class ActivityTabWidget extends TabActivity {  
 private TabHost mTabHost = null;  
 private Intent ihome, imusic, iabout;  

 @Override  
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
  setContentView(R.layout.main);  

  //create tab host to add tabs  
  mTabHost = getTabHost();  


  LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.main,  
    mTabHost.getTabContentView(), true);  

  // create intents to load another page on Tabs  
  ihome = new Intent(ActivityTabWidget.this, ActivityHome.class);  
  imusic = new Intent(ActivityTabWidget.this, ActivityMusic.class);  
  iabout= new Intent(ActivityTabWidget.this,ActivityAboutMe.class);  

  // create tabs and add to TabHost  

  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")  
    .setIndicator(" Home ")  
    .setContent(ihome));  

  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3")  
    .setIndicator(" Music ")  
    .setContent(imusic));  

  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3")  
    .setIndicator(" About Me ")  
    .setContent(iabout));  

  // set default selected tab  
  mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);  

 }  
}
```

Then you need to create Three Activities

1. ActivityHome.class
2. ActivityMusic.class
3. ActivityAboutMe.class

so the output will be like this..

[image]